# Memory leak when changing GLKBaseEffect

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, glkbaseeffect

I am trying to render two objects with GLKit.  Initially I was trying to do this:

```
[Cube drawViewController:self.effect CameraMatrix:&lookatmatrix];

//turn off lighting for floor
self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_FALSE;
[Floor drawViewController:self.effect CameraMatrix:&lookatmatrix];
self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
```

However this seems to cause a memory leak.  I read somewhere that:

Each change of the "fundamental" properties (lightingType, lightModelTwoSided, colorMaterialEnabled, ...) will cause a new shader program to be loaded with the next "prepareToDraw" call.

If I remove the self.effect.light0.enabled changes and run the following I do not have a memory leak issue:

```
[Cube drawViewController:self.effect CameraMatrix:&lookatmatrix];

//turn off lighting for floor
//self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_FALSE;
[Floor drawViewController:self.effect CameraMatrix:&lookatmatrix];
//self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
```

I tried creating 2 different GLKBaseEffects but the second object will not render the floor correctly.

drawViewController calls prepareToDraw and looks like the following:

```
-(void) drawViewController:(GLKBaseEffect *)effect CameraMatrix:(GLKMatrix4 *)cameramatrix
{
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(*cameramatrix, modelMatrix);
    effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
    [effect prepareToDraw];
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *TextureID);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(modelvertdata.vertexArray);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, modelvertdata.NumVerts);
}
```

Comment: I experience the same issue ... using GLKBaseEffect just eats my memory!